# facebook login-button - registration-url doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to integrate the facebook registration-login plugin in my site.

Following is an example that is trying just to implement the login button.

According to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/):
"If the user has not registered for your site, they will be redirected to the URL you specify in the registration-url parameter."

However this doesn't happen. When the user clicks on the login button and he isn't registered in my site yet, the same page, with the login button, reloads.

```
<?php

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : 'MY APP ID', 
                  channelUrl : 'MY CHANNEL URL', 
                  status     : true, 
                  cookie     : true, 
                  oauth      : true, 
                  xfbml      : true  
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout',    function(response) {
                  window.location.reload();
                });
              };
            </script>

        <fb:login-button
           registration-url="...my site's address/test.php" 
           on-login="console.log(arguments)"
        />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this site: https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/my and remove your app and try again! You will see, it works! ;)

Comment: I've tried to follow the link. I couldn't find where to remove my app. I'll appreciate if you can explain please, Where should I remove it from? And why should I remove it?

Comment: ok, seems like you haven't connected to your app yet (what my fail was as I was implementing the login button).
Now I tested it again on my own website and noticed, that the registration-url-redirect don't work for me too, **BUT:** only in firefox! In Opera, Chrome and Internet Explorer 9 the redirect work fine! What browser do you use?

Comment: do you have tried the HTML5 button instead of XFBML? or use `data-registration-url=""` instead of `registration-url=""`
Also i noticed that the bug appears to me only on firefox when i am clicking on the facebook icon of registration button. If i click on the text, it works as well!

Comment: Thank you for your time. data-registration-url doesn't work either. If by HTML5 you mean that one: `<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1" data-registration-url="test.php"></div>`, well,
I've tried it and got the same results. :(    I'm wondering how is it that the exact same code works on your end and not on mine

Comment: Oh, what about your first comment that  haven't connected to your app yet. What do you mean by saying that? Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I meant, when i was testing the login button first time, I haven't noticed that it can't redirect to registration-url because i was already connected to my app. At this moment my website only refreshs as yours do, when i was clicking the button. After revoke connection to my app it works.
if this might be the problem, use this link to disconnect from your app: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?method=delete&access_token=<YOUR TOKEN>` (You can see access token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ )
If there is no token, you're not connected and problem is an other

Comment: OK, as I clicked that later link, there wasn't any token. I connected to my facebook account and a token appeared. I planted it in the first url you mentioned and only the word "true" showed up. Now on my site the text of the login buttons (both the XFBML and the one mentioned in the comment before) changed from "Login" to "Register", when I click on them a message shows up saying: "Unable to load the registration form for . You may have previously blocked this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy settings to unblock this app.". I'm pretty confused, I've to investigate the whole thing.

Comment: Yea, thats what i meant. The button only redirect to registration-url if you are not connected to your app! If the button shows "Login" you are either logged out of FB or you are logged in with FB AND connected with your app.
The first link ( https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/my ) show you all apps you are connected with (if you are logged in with facebook). There you could revoke connection to your app to try out the button... this is the "public way".
The 2nd link is for developer use i.e. an "unsubscribe button" on your website. Thats why it replies "true" ;)

Comment: Got it, Thanks! +1 for the back and forth.